# Removing of white space in Tkinter widget with .tex expression embedded

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, matplotlib-widget

I'm creating an application that generates mathematical expressions, displays them and allows to check whether student simplified it correctly. I have tried `sympy.preview` as an approach but it was not satisfactory due to latex installation required. That's why I decided to use `matplotlib.backends.` `backend_tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg` as an option.

At the moment I'm trying to create `tkinter` widget with expression displayed on top of and call `grid()` method on it like this:

```
from matplotlib import use
use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 1), dpi=50)
ax = fig.gca()

ax.text(0.0, 0.0, "$" + r'x\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}' + "$", fontsize=40, bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))
ax.axis('off')
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(True)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
canvas_widget.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky="nesw")
canvas.draw()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

There are two problems:

1. Expression is not displayed on the left leavin some gap.
2. Expression doesn't fit into widget

My desired result is:

[image]

I have tried to change `figsize` and `ax.text` position but I couldn't find a pattern that makes position of image stable. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Update:** fortunately I managed to find a simple solution. Don't know why but inserting `fig.tight_layout(pad=0)` before `canvas.draw()` solves everything.

Comment: Best do not set the axes off (`ax.axis('off')`). That will allow you to see where the positionning comes from.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks. I've been experimenting with this option too. It helps me to see positioning.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks again, I was testing your solution on different topic and succeeded to find a way to solve it.